# Ubuntu OAuth client

Tags: user-management

Please, what solution should I use, when we already have oauth server (our own gitlab) and we have some ubuntu machines and want the machines to accept logins (as its users), that can login to our gitlab, so that we do not need to add users manually to each machine.
*Is it possible to set it up such that it accepts logins in addition to already existing machine logins and the logins also work for ssh remote access? (we already have ssh set up and working)

(Iam only able to google how to setup oauth server, which we already have. Also I do not know any user managment tools and our collegue said he knew it 5 years ago, but it surely evolved so he is totally unsure.)

Comment: The other way around might have been easier: set up LDAP, make [Ubuntu machines](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.en) and [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html) use LDAP.

Comment: Thx! Any 'ldap for absolute and total noobs' links? (Iam selftaught and I only know not to write 'rm rf' :D)

Comment: The Ubuntu LTS server guide I linked to in the previous comment is a good starting point